# Does hachoir metadata or libextractor extract covers from ID3v2 and all another formats?

Tags: python, metadata, id3v2, hachoir-parser

I've tried to use hachoir-metadata to work with multimedia files but I can't find how to parse covers in ID3v2 metadata. I see in source code that it know about a lot of covers tags but dose not return any in parser. And I've even tried to use libextractor and python-extractor binding and also didn't find how to fetch cover from multimedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with hachoir-metadata is that they search only "text" field for every ID3 chunk, but write image in "img_data" field not in "text" field.

So, hachoir-metadata can not extract images from metadata because this problem in source code.